# AngularJS ng-swith-when on first 2 letters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I really searched into that problem and did not find a solution for that. Is it possible to have a ng-repeat combined with ng-switch on (first_3_letters_of) "xy"? My problem looks like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="channel in device.channels" ng-switch on=<!--first_3_Letters_of-->"channel.id"> 
        <span ng-switch-when="01_">
                <!-- insert some graphic-->             
        </span>
        <span ng-switch-when="02_">
                <!-- insert some other graphic-->               
        </span>         
</span>
```

I want to check just the prefix of an ID, because adding another attribute to the framework is a lot of work with many constraints. Changing the ID name would be easy and gives a first look into what channel-type it is.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in angular filter *limitTo*, like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="channel in device.channels" ng-switch on="channel.id | limitTo : 3"> 
    <span ng-switch-when="01_">
            <!-- insert some graphic-->             
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-when="02_">
            <!-- insert some other graphic-->               
    </span>
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you very much! If you knew that its the keyword "limitTo" its easy :P.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the ng-switch just a shorthand for a bunch of ngIf calls?
Do you specifically have to switch?

Maybe something like:

```
<span ng-repeat="channel in device.channels"> 
        <span ng-if="'01_' == channel.id.substring(0,3)">
                <!-- insert some graphic-->             
        </span>
        <span ng-if="'02_' == channel.id.substring(0,3)">
                <!-- insert some other graphic-->               
        </span>         
</span>
```

Comment: I don't get it... You prefer a *bunch of ngIfs* rather than an ngSwitch?